# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder why my query isn't working, I am supposed to leave the `WHERE 1` just as it is; I've used it like this many times before but for this query, it is not working.

```
SELECT * FROM industries WHERE 1 AND IN id (11,8,1,2,3,4,5,6) ORDER BY position ASC
```

Here is the error I get:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN id (11,8,1,2,3,4,5,6) ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: It's too straightforward.

Comment: `1 and in`? Perhaps if you weren't trying to invent your own "sql" syntax and used the real SQL syntax rules...

Comment: check the order of keyword and column names in the query

Comment: No , I have used the WHERE 1 and IN before ... I am pretty sure it's not that .. that's what the query function outputs ...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: @user3267381 WHERE 1 is always **TRUE** - there is like no need of having it there.

Comment: u obviously didnt read what I mentioned , I just copied and pasted it as the function outputs it ... I know it is always true ..

Comment: the guy made a silly query mistake.. you all have.. don't down vote the question - everything you need is there to solve it

Comment: Note to readers: yes, the `WHERE 1 AND` is redundant, but it's quite a common construction. This is sometimes used by query builders to avoid having to work out whether a subclause needs an `AND` in front of it (or a `WHERE` at all). The query _always_ has a `WHERE 1` and then any subsequent subclauses are _always_ prefixed with an `AND`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This query should work:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM industries WHERE id IN (11,8,1,2,3,4,5,6) ORDER BY position ASC
   ```
2. ASC is default, you can write just

   ```
    ORDER BY position
   ```

Comment: Thanks to say why for future references. It's because `id` and the `IN` keywords were inverted.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM industries WHERE id IN (11,8,1,2,3,4,5,6) ORDER BY position
```

Don't use `WHERE 1` it does not make sense here. It is useless because it is evaluated as (always) **true**

And the correct syntax for `IN` is `WHERE <column> IN (list)`

Comment: I knew you were gonna say that but that where 1 is inserted by a function , and I used it like that before and it works , I cant change that function , I am not allowed to

Comment: Well like i said in my edited answer, it's not a problem, only useless

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT * FROM industries WHERE 1 AND id IN (11,8,1,2,3,4,5,6) order by position;
```

Comment: IN id doesn't make sense it should be id IN

Comment: holy crap a downvote and an explanation. thank you sam.  honestly.  Crappy answer gets -1, i agree, thanks for telling me why.

Comment: I changed it since you edited the answer